# .bat random timeout

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a variable / random timeout value, say between 20 and 40.

I need the time out value to be created by some form of random number generator and insert it in the timeout value field.

Any help much appreciated please, this might be a simple task for some of you but it is driving me crazy

Hi. Thank you for that but I am unable to get it to work. Here is the script I am running perhaps you can tell me where I am going wrong.

here is the script I am running

```
start iexplore.exe www.vhstodvd.eu/About-Us.html
timeout 23 
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
```

I would like the time out value set at 23 to vary between say 20 and 40.

Comment: It would be helpful to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

`set /a timeout=%RANDOM% * 21 / 32768 + 20`

%RANDOM% returns an integer between 0 and 32767.

21 is the range of values you want (20 to 40).

32768 is the range of values returned by %RANDOM% (0 to 32767).

20 is the minimum value you want.

Comment: Hi Thank you for that but i am unable to get it to work. here is the script I am running perhaps you can tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: start iexplore.exe www.vhstodvd.eu/About-Us.html
timeout 23 
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe     I would like the timeout value which is set at 23 at the moment to vary between 20 and 40.

Comment: Just replace the timeout value by %timeout% (after get its random value): `start iexplore.exe www.vhstodvd.eu/About-Us.html timeout %timeout% taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe`

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: I think the dividend value must be 32768, otherwise, if the random value is 32767 the final result will be 41.

Comment: Thank you Thank you it works much apreciated.. what or why is the figure 32767 0r 23768 is this an equation ?

Comment: @Phil The %RANDOM% variable returns a random number between 0 and 32767.  As DOS expressions only deals in integers, you'll need to multiply the random number by the range of values you can possibly have (plus 1 for rounding), then divide by 32768, which is the number of possibilities there are, then add your minimum permissible value.